# Realvnc - Trouble connecting using hostname

Tags: vnc

Hi I am having trouble connecting to Pi3B (Buster) using wifi. It works fine when using IP address but gives "No such host is known" when entering its hostname for access?

I tried entering the following:

Name

Name.local

Name:1

Any ideas where I am going wrong

Comment: "Any ideas where I am going wrong" - start with asking a question with no information.

Comment: What is "Name:1" supposed to mean?

Answer (score -1):

Turns out you just need to install Samba to make the host name visible

sudo apt-get -y install samba

and accept the default

Comment: To install a complete network directory sharing system only to solve a name resolution problem is really overkill!